# Div split pane, with min-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have two 50% divs, but the content of the first div got a min-size.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div style="min-width:1000px">
<label>In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>TEST</label>
</div>
```

With this snippet the first div is not 50% at all, due the min width of its content.

How to force 50% size on first div? (with horizontal scrollbar of course)

Comment: why dont you use `overflow:auto;` in your first column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply on your first column `overflow:auto;`. I use the selector `:first-child`. But I would advice you to create a class `.overflow-auto{ overflow:auto;}` as it is done in Bootstrap 4.

DEMO:

```css
.col-xs-6:first-child{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div style="min-width:1000px">
      <label>In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label>TEST</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS Grid on the parent div and set it to two equal columns.

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

If you include your code, I will be able to see what you currently have and provide better a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To do it you can add the scroll with `overflow:scroll`, also if you want to remove the paddings created by the columns you can use `row-n-gutters` class in the row to use the entire space between columns.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class="row row-no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="overflow:scroll">
    <div style="min-width:1000px">
      <label>In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the In here goes the value of the In here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the value of theIn here goes the vae value of the</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label>TEST</label>
  </div>
</div>
```